# How to find previous element with specific pattern

Tags: javascript

I could not build up the solution how to find the previous element without specific pattern.

**Description:** In the select option below is a simple Select box. The parent items have no `-` or dash, and the parents are created, then the children option values, so always, the children option values have greater value than parent value.

I am trying to find the parent value if a element is selected, if the element selected is parent, then return the parent value.

This is simple and obvious problem but I could not figure out the problem, if anyone could show how to get the above.

**The html is from CMS - Drupal** the html can not be changed

```js
window.addEventListener("load", selectOptionVal);

function selectOptionVal(){
  let selectBox = document.getElementById("edit-field-category");
  
   selectBox.onchange = function(){
    let selectedOption = selectBox.options[selectBox.selectedIndex].value;
    console.log(selectedOption);

    let selectOptionText = selectBox.options[selectBox.selectedIndex].text;
    
    let ifParent = isParent(selectOptionText);
    
    if(ifParent == true){
      parentVal = selectedOption;
    } else {
      parentVal = getParentAboveValue(selectedOption);
    }
    
    console.log(parentVal);
    
    function getParentAboveValue(e){ //argument must be number, and return number, enter option value(selectedOption)
      
    }
    
    function isParent(e){
      if(e[0] == '-'){
        return false;
      } else {
        return true;
      }
    }
    
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="js-form-item form-item js-form-type-select form-type-select js-form-item-field-category form-item-field-category">
      <label for="edit-field-category">Category</label>
        <select data-drupal-selector="edit-field-category" id="edit-field-category" name="field_category" class="form-select">
        <option value="_none">- None -</option>
        <option value="6">Amphibean</option>
        <option value="7">-Frog</option>
        <option value="8">-Salamandar</option>
        <option value="1">Dog</option>
        <option value="3">-Alceschian</option>
        <option value="2">-Bulldog</option>
        <option value="5">-Chihuahua</option>
        <option value="4">-Pug</option>
        <option value="9">ParentOne</option>
        <option value="10">-Child</option>
        <option value="11">-Childdot</option>
        <option value="12">-Childtwo</option>
        <option value="13">-Childanother</option>
        <option value="29">Reptile</option>
        <option value="30">-Snake</option>
        <option value="31">-Crocodile</option>
        <option value="32">-Gecko</option>
        <option value="33">-Lizard</option>
        <option value="34">-Chameleon</option>
        <option value="35">-Cobra</option>
        </select>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `querySelector` to find the selected `<option>` in the `<select>` box, and then navigate backwards with `previousElementSibling` until you hit a parent or nothing like so:

```js
window.addEventListener("load", selectOptionVal);

function selectOptionVal(){
  let selectBox = document.getElementById("edit-field-category");
  
   selectBox.onchange = function(){
    let selectedOption = selectBox.options[selectBox.selectedIndex].value;
    console.log(selectedOption);

    let selectOptionText = selectBox.options[selectBox.selectedIndex].text;
    
    let ifParent = isParent(selectOptionText);
    
    if(ifParent == true){
      parentVal = selectedOption;
    } else {
      parentVal = getParentAboveValue(selectedOption);
    }
    
    console.log(parentVal);
    
    function getParentAboveValue(e){ //argument must be number, and return number, enter option value(selectedOption)
      let opt = selectBox.querySelector(`option[value="${e}"]`);
      //console.log(opt);
      do {
        opt = opt.previousElementSibling;
      } while (opt && !isParent(opt.text)) //Test for found parent or nothing
      return opt ? opt.value : null;
    }
    
    function isParent(e){
      if(e[0] == '-'){
        return false;
      } else {
        return true;
      }
    }
    
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="js-form-item form-item js-form-type-select form-type-select js-form-item-field-category form-item-field-category">
      <label for="edit-field-category">Category</label>
        <select data-drupal-selector="edit-field-category" id="edit-field-category" name="field_category" class="form-select">
        <option value="_none">- None -</option>
        <option value="6">Amphibean</option>
        <option value="7">-Frog</option>
        <option value="8">-Salamandar</option>
        <option value="1">Dog</option>
        <option value="3">-Alceschian</option>
        <option value="2">-Bulldog</option>
        <option value="5">-Chihuahua</option>
        <option value="4">-Pug</option>
        <option value="9">ParentOne</option>
        <option value="10">-Child</option>
        <option value="11">-Childdot</option>
        <option value="12">-Childtwo</option>
        <option value="13">-Childanother</option>
        <option value="29">Reptile</option>
        <option value="30">-Snake</option>
        <option value="31">-Crocodile</option>
        <option value="32">-Gecko</option>
        <option value="33">-Lizard</option>
        <option value="34">-Chameleon</option>
        <option value="35">-Cobra</option>
        </select>
        </div>
```

**Edited with even better solution: previousElementSibling instead of previousSibling, thought of it after posting**

Comment: let me check ... more update could be required

Answer (score 1):

Simply splicing through all the options in the select after the selected one and finding the parent without `-`

```js
function selectOptionVal() {
  let selectBox = document.getElementById("edit-field-category");

  selectBox.addEventListener('change', e => {
    const isParent = e => e[0] != '-';
    const getParentAboveValue = _ => [...selectBox.options].splice(0, selectBox.options.selectedIndex - 1).reverse().find(option => isParent(option.text));
    
    let parentVal;
    let selectOption = selectBox.selectedOptions[0];
    
    if (isParent(selectOption.text)) parentVal = selectOption;
    else parentVal = getParentAboveValue();

    console.log({value: parentVal.value, text: parentVal.text});
  });
}


addEventListener('load', selectOptionVal);
```

```html
<div class="js-form-item form-item js-form-type-select form-type-select js-form-item-field-category form-item-field-category">
  <label for="edit-field-category">Category</label>
  <select data-drupal-selector="edit-field-category" id="edit-field-category" name="field_category" class="form-select">
    <option value="_none">- None -</option>
    <option value="6">Amphibean</option>
    <option value="7">-Frog</option>
    <option value="8">-Salamandar</option>
    <option value="1">Dog</option>
    <option value="3">-Alceschian</option>
    <option value="2">-Bulldog</option>
    <option value="5">-Chihuahua</option>
    <option value="4">-Pug</option>
    <option value="9">ParentOne</option>
    <option value="10">-Child</option>
    <option value="11">-Childdot</option>
    <option value="12">-Childtwo</option>
    <option value="13">-Childanother</option>
    <option value="29">Reptile</option>
    <option value="30">-Snake</option>
    <option value="31">-Crocodile</option>
    <option value="32">-Gecko</option>
    <option value="33">-Lizard</option>
    <option value="34">-Chameleon</option>
    <option value="35">-Cobra</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Please solve - this - this question is from a CMS(drupal) the above markup was copied from the html. So, the html can not be changed, please update answer

Comment: @BrownPaul That's not how Stack Overflow works. You ask a question, you get answers. You should not be updating the question if it invalidates the answers you've already received.

Answer (score 1):

```
  const selected = event.currentTarget.options[event.currentTarget.selectedIndex].value
  selected.includes("-") ? console.log(selected) :  findParent(event)
// if parent is not slected call fucntion findParent()
}

findParent = (event) => {
  const selected = event.currentTarget.options[event.currentTarget.selectedIndex]
// selected item
  const opetionsEls = [...event.currentTarget.options]
// all options
  var index = opetionsEls.indexOf(selected);
// index of selected item from the list  
  let newOptions = opetionsEls.slice(1, index + 1);
// cut options at index of selected item  
  newOptions.reverse()
// reverse options 
  let res = newOptions.find(e => !e.text.includes("-"))
// find first that includes -
  console.log(res.value)
}
```

**Working EXAMPLE:**

```js
let selectBox = document.getElementById("edit-field-category");

selectBox.onchange = function(event) {
  const selected = event.currentTarget.options[event.currentTarget.selectedIndex].value
  selected.includes("-") ? console.log(selected) :  findParent(event)
}

findParent = (event) => {
  const selected = event.currentTarget.options[event.currentTarget.selectedIndex]
  const opetionsEls = [...event.currentTarget.options]
  var index = opetionsEls.indexOf(selected);
  let newOptions = opetionsEls.slice(1, index + 1);
  newOptions.reverse()
  let res = newOptions.find(e => !e.text.includes("-"))
  console.clear()
  console.log(res.value)
}
```

```html
<div class="js-form-item form-item js-form-type-select form-type-select js-form-item-field-category form-item-field-category">
  <label for="edit-field-category">Category</label>
  <select data-drupal-selector="edit-field-category" id="edit-field-category" name="field_category" class="form-select">
    <option value="_none">- None -</option>
    <option value="6">Amphibean</option>
    <option value="7">-Frog</option>
    <option value="8">-Salamandar</option>
    <option value="1">Dog</option>
    <option value="3">-Alceschian</option>
    <option value="2">-Bulldog</option>
    <option value="5">-Chihuahua</option>
    <option value="4">-Pug</option>
    <option value="9">ParentOne</option>
    <option value="10">-Child</option>
    <option value="11">-Childdot</option>
    <option value="12">-Childtwo</option>
    <option value="13">-Childanother</option>
    <option value="29">Reptile</option>
    <option value="30">-Snake</option>
    <option value="31">-Crocodile</option>
    <option value="32">-Gecko</option>
    <option value="33">-Lizard</option>
    <option value="34">-Chameleon</option>
    <option value="35">-Cobra</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: I have the edited the question, other answers also update .. I need the parent option value, not if `parent`

Comment: @BrownPaul Easy fix. Done.

Comment: Dobro izgleda :) +1

Comment: @Ivan86 Hvala :) But after seeing accepted anwser looks like I took a bit more complicated route, but it gets the job done ;)

Answer (score 0):

This code will get you the parent value on child options if that's what you wanted.

```js
window.addEventListener("load", selectOptionVal);

function selectOptionVal() {
  const optionsArray = [];
  const options = document.getElementsByTagName("option");
  let parentValue = "";
  Object.keys(options).map(key => {
    if (options[key].text[0] !== "-") {
      parentValue = options[key].value;
    }
    optionsArray.push({
      text: options[key].text,
      value: options[key].value,
      parent: parentValue
    })
  })

  let selectBox = document.getElementById("edit-field-category");

  selectBox.onchange = function() {
    let selectedOption = selectBox.options[selectBox.selectedIndex].value;
    console.log(selectedOption);

    let selectOptionText = selectBox.options[selectBox.selectedIndex].text;

    parentVal = optionsArray.find(option => option.value === selectedOption).parent;

    console.log(parentVal);


  }
}
```

```html
<div class="js-form-item form-item js-form-type-select form-type-select js-form-item-field-category form-item-field-category">
  <label for="edit-field-category">Category</label>
  <select data-drupal-selector="edit-field-category" id="edit-field-category" name="field_category" class="form-select">
    <option value="_none">- None -</option>
    <option value="6">Amphibean</option>
    <option value="7">-Frog</option>
    <option value="8">-Salamandar</option>
    <option value="1">Dog</option>
    <option value="3">-Alceschian</option>
    <option value="2">-Bulldog</option>
    <option value="5">-Chihuahua</option>
    <option value="4">-Pug</option>
    <option value="9">ParentOne</option>
    <option value="10">-Child</option>
    <option value="11">-Childdot</option>
    <option value="12">-Childtwo</option>
    <option value="13">-Childanother</option>
    <option value="29">Reptile</option>
    <option value="30">-Snake</option>
    <option value="31">-Crocodile</option>
    <option value="32">-Gecko</option>
    <option value="33">-Lizard</option>
    <option value="34">-Chameleon</option>
    <option value="35">-Cobra</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

You need some good changes in javascript only now, by reading the code you can get an understanding of what changed here.

Comment: Please [edit] your question with what changes were made and why. Stack Overflow tries to be a place for answers that help people understand their code, not just get spoonfed the answer.

Comment: I have updated my answer this will work without updating HTML, hope you like it @brown-paul

Answer (score 0):

We use the Element property `previousElementSibling` that is linked to the previous HTML element. To find it, we call your function `getParentAboveValue()`, which is recursively goes through all above Elements until it finds a Parent.

```js
window.addEventListener("load", selectOptionVal);

function selectOptionVal(){
  let selectBox = document.getElementById("edit-field-category");
  
   selectBox.onchange = function(){
    let selectedOption = selectBox.options[selectBox.selectedIndex];
    console.log(selectedOption);

    let selectOptionText = selectedOption.text;
   
    let parentVal;
    
    if(isParent(selectOptionText)){
      parentVal = selectedOption;
    } else {
      parentVal = getParentAboveValue(selectedOption);
    }
    
    
     console.log(parentVal);
    
    function getParentAboveValue(e){
      let prevElem = e.previousElementSibling;
      
      if(isParent(prevElem.text)) {
        return prevElem;
      }
      
      return getParentAboveValue(prevElem);
    }
    
    function isParent(e){
      if(e[0] == '-'){
        return false;
      } else {
        return true;
      }
    }
    
    
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="js-form-item form-item js-form-type-select form-type-select js-form-item-field-category form-item-field-category">
      <label for="edit-field-category">Category</label>
        <select data-drupal-selector="edit-field-category" id="edit-field-category" name="field_category" class="form-select">
        <option value="_none">- None -</option>
        <option value="6">Amphibean</option>
        <option value="7">-Frog</option>
        <option value="8">-Salamandar</option>
        <option value="1">Dog</option>
        <option value="3">-Alceschian</option>
        <option value="2">-Bulldog</option>
        <option value="5">-Chihuahua</option>
        <option value="4">-Pug</option>
        <option value="9">ParentOne</option>
        <option value="10">-Child</option>
        <option value="11">-Childdot</option>
        <option value="12">-Childtwo</option>
        <option value="13">-Childanother</option>
        <option value="29">Reptile</option>
        <option value="30">-Snake</option>
        <option value="31">-Crocodile</option>
        <option value="32">-Gecko</option>
        <option value="33">-Lizard</option>
        <option value="34">-Chameleon</option>
        <option value="35">-Cobra</option>
        </select>
        </div>
```